# Filemaker Pro Date Calculation

Tags: filemaker

I currently have a script issue that didn't transfer correctly from version 18 to the upgrade to version 19. It is an invoice function. If the invoice is created on a certain date, the "Days Due" should show zero, but it incrementally showing a count in reverse on the day I upgraded (12/26/22) as day zero. For example, a new invoice date of 12/30/22 shows days due -4 days when it should be 0 days. The invoice is hung up on 12/26 as day zero.

I am guessing it is a simple script adjustment for a function that didn't convert to the new version, but I am not good enough with scripts to fix the problem. The current calculation script for the Days Due is:

`If(GetAsNumber(Amount Paid)<GetAsNumber(Order Total);Today- Invoice Date;0)`

The invoice date is a date-type field with 'Creation Date' as the option. When the amount is paid, the 'Days Due' calculation returns to zero, which it correctly does.

Comment: I found the issue in part. The General Preference: 'Enlarge window contents to improve readability' is missing in Filemaker 19. Not sure why they removed such a critical selection.

I could Script Trigger OnFirstWindowOpen this to update the date field:

'Set Error Capture [On]
New Window [Style: Document]
Perform Find [Restore]
Replace Field Contents [With dialog:Off; Invoices::Today; Get(CurrentDate)]
Close Window [Current Window]'

I need both the date updated AND the screen resized OnFirstWindowOpen. Ran together, Filemaker opens the file repeatedly until it runs out of memory.

Comment: Changing the above to:   If(GetAsNumber(Amount Paid)<GetAsNumber(Order Total);Get(CurrentDate) - Invoice Date;0)   Seems to be fix.

Comment: Why would you need a Today field in an Invoices table?

Comment: Its use and purpose are succinctly explained in the initial post.

Comment: I meant why would you need a Today field when - as you so succinctly explained in your added comment - you can simply use Get(CurrentDate) in an unstored calculation and avoid all the potential harms of your original method, such as loss of the last-modified feature and risk of user collision.

Comment: @ArtiosMedia, can you please edit your original question and with the additional information in your comments.